Should we have a specific tag for questions that ask about the name of a study? And if so, what?
We had a question:

Study on commitment and follow-through

The essential features:

the OP wants to know the name or reference to a study
the OP knows that the study exists and has some details about the study

Question

Should there be a tag for this?
If so, what should the tag be?


The gaming site has a tag for their equivalent line of questions: [identify-this-game]. "identify this study" seems a bit too informal however.

I don't mind "identify-this-study". It's better than anything I can think of, so far.

why not just use [reference-request]? It is used by MO, cstheory.SE, TP.SE, and ling.SE (and maybe others) as the standard "I need a reference for when whatever I am describing appeared".

@ArtemKaznatcheev makes some sense, however that could also mean "I need a reference to support X concept" in my mind

I retagged the 2 old [reference] questions as [reference-request] to be consistent with other stackexchanges.

We already have a tag called reference-request (full disclosure: we had a tag named reference that had 2 questions that I retagged to the new reference-request tag to bring it into existance) with 2 questions. Had the tag existed when I first asked some of my questions, I would have also tagged them as such, and will probably add the tags next time I edit my questions.
This tag is consistent with the tagging convention on other academic Q&A sites like MO, cstheory.SE, TP.SE, and linguistics.SE (and maybe others). 
I would use this tag for:

"identify-this-study" type questions
"what is a good survey or introduction on this topic" type questions, and 
"when did this first appear in the literature" type questions. 

I wouldn't tag a question as reference request just because you want people to include references for what they state in their answers (since that should always be implicitly expected).

+1, I'm all for consistency. And I feel to broader scope it implies isn't too broad. Otherwise we'd have to create other (narrow scope) tags for those as well.

@StevenJeuris yeah, the scope hasn't been a problem on other SE sites.

I propose the tag identify-this-research. It's a bit broader than just studies so it can be applied in more scenarios.
Using this tag would allow us to greatly reduce the length of the title.

What was the the study called that was on commitment and
  follow-through and involved college students attending a follow-up
  event?

... after the tag is applied I would change the title to:

Study on commitment and follow-through involving college students
  attending a follow-up event.

I know it ain't a question, but turning it into a question seems redundant to me, easier solved by applying identify-this-research.

Don't know the blog post, but there was a good SE blog about making good, concise question titles. Don't repeat yourself and don't force it into a question (if the question is obvious) were important points.
